# AvQueuePlayer not playing audio on iPhone, only working on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avqueueplayer

I have added audio files to my Xcode project so that i can play them locally using `AvQueuePlayer` (a subclass of `AVPlayer`). In order to do this I must create an array of `[AVPlayerItems]` which is then supplied to the `AVQueuePlayer` to be played sequentially... here is my code ...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

//fills songNameArray with the appropriate part of file name, example: print(songNameArray[0]) -> prints -> "SongName.mp3"
   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!
  let songFiles = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
    for item in songFiles {
        if item.hasSuffix("mp3") {
            songNameArray.append(item)
            print("appended to songNameArray \(item)")
        }
    }

 //iterates thru songNameArray and uses combineStrings method to form fullSongPath//
    for i in 0...songNameArray.count - 1 {
        fullSongPaths.append(combineStrings(songNameArray[i]))
        print("here are the full song paths \(fullSongPaths[i])")
    }

 func combineStrings(songName: String) -> String {
    let fullSongPath = ("/Users/username/Desktop/Xcode Projects Folder/LocalAudioPlayer/LocalAudioPlayer/" + songName)
    return fullSongPath
    }
}
```

Then, here is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` where a user taps a song to start playing...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      makePlayerItemsArray()

      queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: playerItemsArray)
      queuePlayer?.play()
  }
```

And here is that makePlayerItemsArray function ...

```
    func makePlayerItemsArray () {
       playerItemsArray.removeAll()

       var createdURL = NSURL()
       var createdItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: createdURL)

       for i in 0...fullSongPaths.count - 1 {
           createdURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(fullSongPaths[i])
           createdItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: createdURL)
           playerItemsArray.append(createdItem)
       }
   }
```

This all works perfectly on the computer, the audio starts playing almost immediately after tapping a row. The problem is when i run this on my iPhone no audio comes out. The song never starts playing. And, when running on iPhone, if i tap a row-- then wait a few seconds-- then tap a button that calls `queuePlayer.currentItem.currentTime()`,-- the app crashes on that line, which I believe is due to the `queuePlayer` not having any item to play.

But why, when I run it on my phone does the `queuePlayer` not get the items from `playerItemsArray?`... I am able to print out the contents of the `fullSongPaths` array as well as the contents of the `playerItemsArray` but the queuePlayer wont play them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let fullSongPath = ("/Users/username/Desktop/Xcode Projects Folder/LocalAudioPlayer/LocalAudioPlayer/" + songName)
```

You can't play a song file that's on your *computer* desktop when you're on your *phone*.

I'm surprised that this worked on the simulator, and the fact that it did could be reasonably considered a bug.

The files need to *be* in the *app bundle* itself (so that they are copied onto the phone as part of the app when you build and run it there), and you need to *refer* to them through their URLs as resources within the app bundle (that is, relative purely to the app bundle, because its URL is unimportant and can change).

Comment: Ok thanks for this! I changed my code to  `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType("mp3", inDirectory: nil)
        for i in 0...path.count - 1 {
            print(path[i])
        }`   ... which returns an array of Strings, that are the proper path in the bundle on the mobile device leading to the mp3 file which I then use to create `[NSURLs]` which are then used to create `[AVPlayerItems]` which are playable through the AVQueuePlayer

Comment: Sounds great. If you use `URLsForResources...` you can skip the path-to-URL conversion, and this would be better.